# Is it possible to reorder columns in a data frame so that ABCDE is reordered to ABDCE by specifying to move D to between B and C?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidy

Is it possible to reorder columns in a data frame so that initial order ABCDE is reordered to ABDCE by specifying that you want to move column D from its current location to between B and C?

For example, the `mtcars` dataset has the current order below:

```r
mtcars <- data.frame(mtcars)
> colnames(mtcars)
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

I want to move the column `gear` to a position between `disp` and `hp` by running code that specifically asks to move "gear" to a position between `disp` and `hp`. The result would like like below, in the data frame `mtcars_reordered`.

```r
> colnames(mtcars_reordered)
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "gear" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am" "carb"
```

This would make it easier to reorder data frames without specifying the order of all variables.

Is this possible? If so, how would it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following function.
Argument `swap` is the names of the 3 columns before reordering them.

```
reorder_df_cols <- function(x, swap){
  i_swap <- match(swap, names(x))
  tmp1 <- x[seq_len(i_swap[1])]
  vars <- x[rev(i_swap[-1])]
  tmp2 <- x[-c(seq_len(i_swap[1]), i_swap[-1])]
  cbind(tmp1, vars, tmp2)
}

data(mtcars, package = "datasets")

swap <- c("disp", "hp", "gear")
colnames(reorder_df_cols(mtcars, swap))
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "gear" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"  
#[10] "am"   "carb"
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a tidyverse verb for that: `relocate`

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% relocate(gear, .after=disp) %>% names()
## [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "gear" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"  
## [11] "carb"
```